# OpenLdap - how to make the attribute uidNumber auto-generated?

Tags: ldap, openldap

in my ldap user creation just want to make the attribute uidNumber auto-generated. a unique auto-generated so that i can use that as the primary-key or unique user id.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. OpenLDAP doesn't support it.

Comment: ooops. @EJP, i have found some referrence that i need to create an ObjectClass attribute? see this 
[7:21] 
http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201112/msg00241.html

Comment: You need to add the objectClass attribute if you are using the LDIF solution mentioned in your citation. It doesn't change this answer.